# Regex - Find and replace single quotes between quotes

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have company array where lots of company name (array key) contains Single quotes.
Just wanted to escape Single quotes character in between the **`Starting`** & **`Ending`** single quotes in `array key`.

**regex:**

```
('[^']*)'s([^']*')
```

**Samples:**

```
'BJs Wholesale Club' => 'A',
'BJ's Wholesale Club' => 'A',
'Dillard's' => 'A',
'Divi's Labs' => 'A',
'Divis Labs' => 'A',
'ESKAY K 'N' (PVT) LTD' => 'B',
'Nahar Ind'l Enterprises' => 'A',
'Toys 'R' Us' => 'A',
'ToysR Us' => 'A',
```

**Required Output:**

```
'BJs Wholesale Club' => 'A',
'BJ\'s Wholesale Club' => 'A',
'Dillard\'s' => 'A',
'Divi\'s Labs' => 'A',
'Divis Labs' => 'A',
'ESKAY K \'N\' (PVT) LTD' => 'B',
'Nahar Ind\'l Enterprises' => 'A',
'Toys \'R\' Us' => 'A',
'ToysR Us' => 'A',
```

My regex doesn't work for company contains other thant `\'s` or more than one single quote

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/23aBEI/2

Comment: You probably won't be able to do this in Notepad++ itself; it uses a smaller subset of regex, and you can't do any processing with the match. You could do this fairly easily with JavaScript, though. I'll work on an answer.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat A smaller subset of regex? It uses the boost library, which is quite complex. "can't do any processing with the match" depends on what you call processing, but it can for example replace the match while referencing capturing groups. That said, I agree regex alone isn't a good tool for this task.

Comment: @Aaron, as mentioned in subject line, need to escape single quotes in between starting & ending quotes.

Answer (score 2):

This should match every single quote you want to escape :

```
(?<!^)'(?=.*' =>)
```

It works by selecting every single quote that isn't at the beginning of the line (`(?<!^)`) and is followed at some point by the `' =>` part (`(?=.*' =>)`) by using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Replacing all occurences by `\\'` in notepad++ gives the following result :

```
'BJs Wholesale Club' => 'A',
'BJ\'s Wholesale Club' => 'A',
'Dillard\'s' => 'A',
'Divi\'s Labs' => 'A',
'Divis Labs' => 'A',
'ESKAY K \'N\' (PVT) LTD' => 'B',
'Nahar Ind\'l Enterprises' => 'A',
'Toys \'R\' Us' => 'A',
'ToysR Us' => 'A',
```

Comment: @Anon30 I've tested it in notepad++ with your sample and it worked, care to check? You should replace all by `\\'`.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, works like a charm. Could you please explain your regex

Comment: @Anon30 I've improved my second sentence which explained how my regex worked.

Answer (score 1):

As Notepad++ supports PCRE (which allows us to use lookbehind), and it also supports multi-line, we can do it using the following:

Vairable lookbehind: [`(?<!^|=> )'(?! =>|,$)`](https://regex101.com/r/23aBEI/3)

Without vairable lookbehind: [`(?<!^)(?<!=> )'(?! =>)(?!,$)`](https://regex101.com/r/23aBEI/4)

Flags: multi-line. Replace with: `\\'`

Comment: It currently fails to compile because PCRE does not support variable-length lookbehind (.NET flavor is one of the few that do). This can be easily fixed by splitting your lookbehind in two. I've tested `(?<!^)(?<! => )'(?! =>|,$)` in notepad++ and it works.

Comment: Try the "without variable lookbehind" version.

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches the whole company names (using the greedyness of the **+** operator).

```
'([a-zA-Z0-9\(\)' ]+)'
```

If the original string also contains the "=> 'A'" and you don't want to parse that, you can use this:

```
^'([a-zA-Z0-9\(\)' ]+)'
```

**Note:** you will need to activate the m flag to make this one work

In group 1 you will have your company name

Comment: OP doesn't want to extract the company name, he wants to escape single-quotes in the company name

Comment: @Aaron Oh, I misunderstood. Leaving this here in case it helps, but you seem to be right.